# How to add matrices in python

Tags: python, matrix

How can I add matrices (list of lists) in python? I know that I can do this:

```
X = [[12,7,3],
    [4 ,5,6],
    [7 ,8,9]]

Y = [[5,8,1],
    [6,7,3],
    [4,5,9]]

result = [[0,0,0],
         [0,0,0],
         [0,0,0]]

# iterate through rows
for i in range(len(X)):
   # iterate through columns
   for j in range(len(X[0])):
       result[i][j] = X[i][j] + Y[i][j]

for r in result:
   print(r)
```

But what if the the input of the two lists have different numbers of rows or columns? I need to check first to see if the number of rows and columns are the same before adding and I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `numpy` for this?

Comment: if A is an n × m matrix and B is an m × p matrix, their matrix product AB is an n × p matrix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: Using numpy the matrix multiplication can be done even using the common multiplication operators, there is absolutely no need for all this mess...

Comment: Yes please try not to use numpy.

Comment: I'm not trying to multiply the matrices though. I need to ADD them

Comment: If all you want to do is check that they have the same dimensions, just do `(assert len(X) == len(Y)) and (len(X[0]) == len(Y[0]))` (assuming that you know all sub-lists will be of the same length)

Comment: Oops sorry, addition is still the same behavior though, and i was to comment what @CactusWoman just commented, this is what you need if not numpy.

Comment: Thank you guys! This helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the size check and then build the result directly with a doubly-nested list comprehension.  Numpy is better, but if you want to avoid an **import**, this will do.

```
X = [[12,7,3],
     [4 ,5,6],
     [7 ,8,9]]

Y = [[5,8,1],
     [6,7,3],
     [4,5,9]]

if len(X) == len(Y) and len(X[0]) == len(Y[0]):
    result = [[X[i][j] + Y[i][j] for j in range(len(X[0]))]
              for i in range(len(X))]

print result
```

Output:

```
[[17, 15, 4], [10, 12, 9], [11, 13, 18]]
```

Comment: the above code will throw an error if the dims don't match, right?

Comment: Only because **result** isn't defined.  To throw a proper exception, add an **else** clause of your choice.